# What is the best way to respond to this pincer joseki deviation?

Tags: go, joseki

Every now and again when I approach a corner, opponent plays 1-space pincer and I jump out, my opponent immediately peeps. This seems like *aji keshi* and bad shape, but I've been stumped as to how to really take advantage of it. Normally what I would get out of this joseki is a nice influential wall facing the center, but now it seems I must sacrifice **my** corner aji to get the wall.

```
$$cm1 Should W connect?
$$ +---------------------------------------+
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . X . O . . . . . |
$$ | . . . , . . . . . , . . 1 . . X . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . O . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
```

If W connects (below), she is free to invade the corner in the future and can connect underneath to 4 if necessary, so is chasing B's group the way to proceed

```
$$cm1 W does have options...
$$ +---------------------------------------+
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . 4 . X . O . . . . . |
$$ | . . . , . . . . . , . . 1 2 . X . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . O . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . 5 . . . . 3 . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
```

However, if the normal joseki were played out before black peeped (again, below) W would probably be happy to solidify her wall and then jump in the corner. The better way for B to cut would be 1 at 2.

```
$$cm1 A poor way for black to cut
$$ +---------------------------------------+
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . X . X X X . O . . 4 . . |
$$ | . . . , . . . . O O O X 1 3 . X . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . O . . . . O 2 O . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . X . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
```

But without the wall already in place, W has difficulty mimicking this result. So what should W do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

White's connection and pincer sequence in another answer works well only if White has a stone (or stones) around the star point D16 in the upper left corner. Then, the 7th stone on J16 is both a pincer and an extension.

```
$$Wcm1 Good for W
$$ +-------------------+
$$ |...................|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...........2.1.....|
$$ |...O....7,..45.X...|
$$ |...........a.3.....|
$$ |...........8....6..|
$$ |.............9.....|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...,.....,.....,...|
```

On the other hand,

```
$$Wcm1 Bad for W
$$ +-------------------+
$$ |...................|
$$ |...................|
$$ |......0....2.1.....|
$$ |...X....7,..45.X...|
$$ |...........a.3.....|
$$ |...........8....6..|
$$ |.............9.....|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...,.....,.....,...|
```

Otherwise, White should invade the upper right corner at the 3-3 point, r17 with move 5. If Black blocks at r 16, White will connect this stone to the kakari stone.

More likely, Black will block at Q17. This captures the kakari stone on O17, but Black's stones are overconcentrated.

```
$$Wcm1 B is overconcentrated. W is free to play at A or tenuki.
$$ +-------------------+
$$ |...................|
$$ |..............657..|
$$ |...........X.O821..|
$$ |...X.....,..X..X3..|
$$ |.............O.4...|
$$ |................9..|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...,.....,.....,...|
```

Either way, the White stone on O15 remains "loose," and in a position to cancel Black's outside influence.

Comment: I added in some diagrams, please change them if they don't reflect what you meant!

Answer (score 4):

Good question.  White usually jumps into the corner in this joseki; if he jumps out he is ready to fight if necessary.  When Black peeps he is giving you a wall that you can use to counterattack his pincer stone.

[eidogo](http://eidogo.com) recommends W7, which denies Black a base on the side while being harder to press down.

```
$$Wcm1
$$ +-------------------+
$$ |...................|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...........2.1.....|
$$ |...,....7,..45.X...|
$$ |...........a.3.....|
$$ |...........8....6..|
$$ |.............9.....|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...................|
$$ |...,.....,.....,...|
```

Black jumping out to B8 leaves a weak point at `a`.  Note that the corner can still be invaded and that White might get to block off the right side.  How this develops will depend on the rest of the board, I think, but it doesn't seem bad for White.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for white:

```
$$cm1
$$ +---------------------------------------+
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . X . O . 2 3 . . |
$$ | . . . , . . . . . , . . 1 . 4 X . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . O . a . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
```

2 might also be played at a.